# Getting error trying install visual in python

Tags: python, pip, installation

I am trying to install visual package and getting this error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement visual (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for visual

I have tried these commands :
py -m pip install visual 
pip install visual

the pip is upgraded.

any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Per [this search](https://pypi.org/search/?q=visual&o=) on PyPI, there is no package named "visual", which is why you're getting that error.

Comment: Well I saw a program line : 
from visual import *
any idea why it works?